# Is there a way to format the output of sbt's show command?

Tags: scala, sbt

For example, if I run 'show dependency-classpath' I get a really really long single line since the default output format is the toString() of an ArrayBuffer. Is there any pretty-print option so this output is easier to read?

Answer (score 3):

There is a new `export` command in 0.13 designed to show classpaths and compile/run commands in a form usable on the command line.  For example,

```
> export dependencyClasspath
/home/user/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.1/lib/scala-library.jar:/home/user/.ivy2/cache/com.sun.jmx/jmxri/jars/jmxri-1.2.1.jar
```

The task has to explicitly output this format, whereas `show` just calls `toString` on whatever the result is.  There isn't another alternative to print one per line or anything like that.

Comment: Perhaps `show` could also have some ability to be overridden by the task, but the options expand pretty quickly, like what to do for long strings.  Pull requests and/or mailing list discussions are welcome here.